# What is an author?

Tags: logic

If you make a program to write a book, are you considered the author?

I’m sorry if this is off topic, but I couldn’t tell if that was included in the ‘on-topic’ list of acceptable questions, and I didn’t have the 5 rep to ask on philosophy meta.

Comment: A writer writes or has written something. An author has published something.

Comment: The point of the question is: if you write a program to write something, is that considered as if you wrote it? I wasn’t trying to bring a difference between writing and publishing in regards to being an author.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but it would seem that if you write the code that writes a book you are the "author" of both. As far as I know, "author" is not some well-defined philosophical term, outside of copyright law. If you make a picture with a camera you may not be a painter, but you are still the creator or "author" of the picture. To dig deeper, you might check out Walter Benjamin's famous essay "Art in the Age of Mechanical Reproduction."  The arts are pretty used to many kinds of machine intervention by now.

Comment: I suppose it depends on how much in the final work is owed to the program itself, how much to the language/platform in which it is written, and how much the program controls the output. If the program amounts to selecting some recursion from a list provided that generates fractal landscapes or music scores based on randomly generated values I am not sure that program's author is the work's author, or that the work is "art" that has an author at all. For a possibility of computers as authors see Hertzman's discussion in [Can Computers Create Art?](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.04486)

Comment: For taking a picture, you can get credit for setting up the picture. But for writing, wouldn’t it fall more under the category of derivative works? Can it be classified as a question of “If you directly influenced a work of art, how much of that work can you take credit for?” ? Or is that different since for a computer program you are the direct contributor to that work of art, only through a roundabout way?

Comment: I do not think there is an objective core to taking credit, it is a social convention. The point of credit and authorship is to socially encourage production of items that require effort to produce, it is not parsing creative statuses or inputs. For computer art it may eventually be settled by law, but not from philosophical considerations. The analogy with derivative works is problematic because computers, as they are today, are not agents that can be independent contributors.

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders Not according to the dictionary. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/author

Comment: @Nelson Alexander You say that "if you write the code that writes a book you are the "author" of both."  So W/O going into the linguistic analysis (and legalisms and facts like authors  also have to get published, etc.), as  deployed by Conifold and Wrigley, to essentially dodge the question and DISsolve the issue/problem, I wonder if you would say the same if a code is written "to write books," [plural]  rather than "to write A book," while assuming an "essentialist" universe in which words like author actually have "meaning", say  as defined by D Webster #1 def in above link.

Comment: @ Conifold  I'm curious as to how you would address the question I posed to Alexander in the above comment.  That is the difference, if any, [in an essentialist universe where words have "meaning" in the traditional sense] between writing code that writes books, rather than writing code to write a [singular] particular book.   Which, I presume is why Alexander did not initially "understand" the query.

Comment: @Nelson Alexander Is my reformulated question to you in above comment  relevant to why you were intitally uncertain whether you understood the question (and posited the photographer analogy)?

Comment: @gonzo. Author is not a technical term and simply means one who "fathers, produces, or creates." Any "artifact" will have at least one human "author." If the book produced by the code produced by the creator of that code has no other intervening person in the process, I would say that one person is the "author" of that artifact, and/or the two artifacts, code and book. Who would contest this claim to "authorship"? Of course, one can always claim some definition of "author" that comes up with a different opinion, but the original question was not so strictly defined.

Comment: Agreed, @Nelson Alexander,  I tried to adress these issues in my answer by distinguishing between two different definitions and two different  states of affairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, the question may be ambiguous. First, I assume that you are not asking the question in the philosophically uninteresting context of intellectual property law, or whether the program can also get the book published or not.

Are you asking whether (1) the writer of code [ a program] that is capable of writing [and does write]  **A** *[particular]* book can be considered the book's author.  Or do you wonder (2) whether the  writer of code of a program that is capable of *writing books [plural, generally]* can be considered the author of all the books written by that program?  While agreeing that the term "author" is to be defined, with Webster, as (A) "the writer of a literary work (such as a book),"  or (B) "one that originates or creates something [published or not]."   These strike me different questions.

It seems to me that an interesting and complex conundrum is posed by question (1), in the context of definition (A). As to definition B, it seems clear that the coder originated/created a program *that writes books*, but less clear that the coder created/authored any particular book written by the program  -- notwithstanding the philosophically uninteresting tenets of intellectual property law, or whether the book was published or not.

ADDENDUM:  In considering the issue, one may want to consider the distinction Aristotle made between **Material Cause** - the stuff out of which something is made --in the case of authorship of a literary work this may include the author's intention as manifested by his in putting particular sentences/paragraphs/chapters together (as opposed to coding syntax into a sentence or book generator), and **Efficient Cause** - the antecedent condition that brought the thing about (the coder is and antecedent condition to the book's existence/being written).

The legal notion of **Proximate Cause** might also be relevant to consider:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximate_cause#Efficient_proximate_cause.  The analogy in the present case with the legal notion of "proximate cause," though strained,  might be something like "ordinary language usage" of the term "author," or the "language game" in which terms like "author," "painter" "sculptor," "painter" are used are used.

Comment: Did you mean Noah Webster, not Daniel?

Comment: I believe the key distinction is that an author is assumed to be a conscious, creative, intentional being, human or perhaps divine. So whatever artifact is generated by that being was authored by that being. The claim to authorship is only contestable when another being capable of intensions and authorship comes into the process. Someone else buys the program and generates the book, etc. In any case, the program itself can make no claims to "authorship."

Comment: Well done @Aleksandr A. Adamov.   Correction made.  Thank you.

Comment: @ Nelson Alexander I was in the process of authoring an addendum addressing the very issue you bring up when you posted.  Also, that "the program itself, or better, the code,  can make no claims to "authorship" would seem to be philosophically irrelevant.  It may be that these  cases is sui generis and there is no "author", in the strict/proper/traditional sense.  Can one say that the coder of a three D printer's program whose function is to print, say, human busts is the sculptor of all busts printed?  Who is the videographer of surveilnce vids taken by a camera fixed to a post.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more general question of whether AI could create intellectual property, which is now actively discussed in the legal world.  Here's an article about whether AI should be considered an inventor in some cases:
https://www.technologyreview.com/2020/01/08/102298/ai-inventor-patent-dabus-intellectual-property-uk-european-patent-office-law/
As it points out, there's a related question whether animals should be able to get intellectual property, such as in the case of the "monkey selfie".
https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2018/04/monkey-selfie-lawsuit-finally-ends-court-affirms-adorable-macaque-cant-sue/

Answer (score 0):

I think the obvious and pragmatic answer to this question is: Who gets paid by the publisher? You seem to be thinking about 'writing a book' as the simple, technical task of putting words down in grammatically correct forms, which even a decent non-AI computer could likely be programmed to do. But being an author involves more than simply writing words, much of which is specifically *social* tasks: choosing publications to submit to; negotiating a fee; receiving and reviewing editorial suggestions, and editing and rewriting weak sections; deciding on publication formats, a title, cover images, and other frillery; even deciding what to spend the received money on. A machine that could do all these things — heck a machine that could simply argue it has  *right* to do such things — would probably have to be accepted as an intelligence and be credited as an author. A machine that cannot is just a tool doing the technical task of writing sentences, and credit of authorship ought to go to the programmer.

It may seem paradoxical, but one of the defining features of a human-level intelligence is that it has the capacity to recognize that it is *not being treated* as a human-level intelligence, and to object to that condition. It's meaningless to talk about the intrinsic 'human' rights of anything that lacks the level of self-reference necessary to complain that its *own* intrinsic rights are being violated.

Comment: If the author doesn’t copyright his work, and someone else does, that other person would be the one negotiating the publisher’s fee, no?

Comment: @Doragon: Sure. But the original author can contest it, if he thinks it's unfair to him. Don't take that specific statement quite so literally; this is *philosophy* site.

Comment: I know, I was just contesting the definition that the author is the one who gets paid.

Comment: @Doragon: I know that, too.   but in context, I didn't mean 'gets paid' as the simple technical action of getting a check; I meant 'gets paid' as a socially intensive *interaction* of seeking out and arranging payment.

Comment: I still don’t think that payment is a fair way to determine the author, since before he contests and regains copyright is he not the author? Also for plagiarized work, should the person who plagiarized the work be considered the true author? Until he’s found out, he’s getting the money.